# Stroke quality/anti-aliasing with svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to make an animated speech bubble using svgs but I've noticing that the anti-aliasing on the strokes lacks sharpness and has a distinct smudge to it. I've tried fixing the problem by rounding my calculations but that only made the smudging worse - What can I do to get hard 1px thick black lines?

HTML:

```
<div id="inset">
    <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#inset {
 width: 20%;
 height: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
}

#svg {
}
```

Javascipt:

```
$(function() {

    var sponsorBubble = function(el, html, cornerRad) {
        this.html = html,
        this.width = el.parent().width(),
        this.x_center = (el.parent().width()/2),
        this.height = el.parent().height(),
        this.arrowWidth = (el.parent().width()/4),
        this.arrowHeight = (el.parent().height()/8),
        this.cornerRad = cornerRad,
        this.arrowRad = this.cornerRad/3,
        this.arrowControlRatio = this.arrowRad * ((this.arrowWidth/2 - (this.arrowRad*2)) / (this.arrowHeight - (this.arrowRad*2)));

        var bubble = s.path(
            "M" +
            Math.round(this.x_center)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height)
            + ", Q" +
            Math.round(this.x_center - this.arrowRad)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.x_center - this.arrowRad)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height - this.arrowRad)
            + ", Q" +
            Math.round(this.x_center - this.arrowRad)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height - (this.arrowRad*2))
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.x_center)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height - (this.arrowRad*2))
            + ", Q" +
            Math.round(this.x_center + this.arrowRad)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height - (this.arrowRad*2))
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.x_center + this.arrowRad)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height - this.arrowRad)
            + ", Q" +
            Math.round(this.x_center + this.arrowRad)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.x_center)
            + ", " +
            Math.round(this.height)
            + ", Z"
        );

        bubble.attr({ 
            stroke: 'black',
            fill: 'none'
        });

        bubble.animate({
            d:
                "M" + 
                Math.round(this.x_center)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height)
                + ", Q" +
                Math.round(this.x_center - this.arrowRad + this.arrowControlRatio)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.x_center - this.arrowRad)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowRad)
                + ", L" +
                Math.round(this.x_center - (this.arrowWidth/2) + this.arrowRad)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight + this.arrowRad)
                + ", Q" +
                Math.round(this.x_center - (this.arrowWidth/2) + this.arrowRad - this.arrowControlRatio)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.x_center - (this.arrowWidth/2))
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight)
                + ", L" +
                Math.round(this.cornerRad)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight)
                + ", Q" +
                0
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight)
                + ", " +
                0
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight - this.cornerRad)
                + ", L" +
                0
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.cornerRad)
                + ", Q" +
                0
                + ", " +
                0
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.cornerRad)
                + ", " +
                0
                + ", L" +
                Math.round(this.width - this.cornerRad)
                + ", " +
                0
                + ", Q" +
                Math.round(this.width)
                + ", " +
                0
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.width)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.cornerRad)
                + ", L" +
                Math.round(this.width)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight - this.cornerRad)
                + ", Q" +
                Math.round(this.width)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.width - this.cornerRad)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight)
                + ", L" +
                Math.round(this.x_center + (this.arrowWidth/2))
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight)
                + ", Q" +
                Math.round(this.x_center + (this.arrowWidth/2) - this.arrowRad + this.arrowControlRatio)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.x_center + (this.arrowWidth/2) - this.arrowRad)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowHeight + this.arrowRad)
                + ", L" +
                Math.round(this.x_center + this.arrowRad)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height - this.arrowRad)
                + ", Q" +
                Math.round(this.x_center + this.arrowRad - this.arrowControlRatio)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.x_center)
                + ", " +
                Math.round(this.height)
                + ", Z"
            }, 
            100
        );

    };


s = Snap('#svg');

var bubble_obj = new sponsorBubble($('#svg'), "test_content", 15);
});
```

jdfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L5k48hwm/

Answer (score 3):

```
svg path { // or rect, circle, etc
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

Having said that, you can try using jQuery UI `.animate()` to create similar effect like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/14/) example (reverse this animation to match your specs). This avoid the complex path generation and smoother lines.

Update: here's the code snippet.

```js
$('div').append('<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0.00000000" y="0.00000000" width="100%" height="100%" id="svg3" viewbox="0 0 1000 600" >  <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10" d="M916.902,397.331c14.126,0,17.344-9.739,17.344-9.739   c0-27.635,7.992-42.357,26.927-42.357c0,0,13.702,1.668,13.702-14.946c0-0.001,0.619-43.408-1.901-141.244   c-2.514-97.836-9.537-109.333-9.537-109.333c0-14.125-9.129-13.284-9.129-13.284c-24.67,0-53.406,4.151-53.406-30.893   c0,0,1.558-11.866-15.041-11.866c0,0-159.78-14.301-423.823-14.301c-264.041,0-375.12,2.352-375.12,2.352   c-14.125,0-13.284,9.136-13.284,9.136c0,22.479-13.575,42.622-30.319,42.622c0,0-13.705,0.341-13.705,16.949   c0,0-4.551,60.914-4.551,117.724c0,56.808,4.551,126.899,4.551,126.899c0,14.125,9.127,13.28,9.127,13.28   c24.9,0,29.944,10.568,29.944,30.322c0,0,1.038,15.744,25.709,15.744l248.677,5.155c0,0,46.81,25.855,64.76,39.665   c17.952,13.808,27.714,26.235,12.526,41.426c-6.669,6.666-11.966,12.474-9.571,21.187c2.277,8.256,26.797,22.168,29.903,23.746   c0.261,0.127,61.957,30.323,84.796,41.37c16.646,8.047,33.288,16.074,49.292,25.362c2.152,1.253,14.271,9.614,16.804,7.089   c2.484-2.479-11.174-12.959-12.823-14.315c-9.084-7.442-16.206-16.462-24.158-25.027c-12.481-13.465-25.133-26.788-37.746-40.133   c-7.044-7.464-13.884-15.167-21.144-22.43c-1.791-1.79-1.476-4.571,0.699-7.001c7.682-8.531,25.246-28.013,27.384-30.14   c2.739-2.731-1.814-7.121-1.814-7.121l-62.959-51.678L916.902,397.331z"/>  </svg>');

$('div').draggable({
    handle: 'rect'
});

$('div').animate({
    width: "500px",
    height: "300px",
    top: "0px",
    left: "0px"
}, 2000).animate({
    width: "100px",
    height: "60px",
    top: "240px",
    left: "230px"
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100px; height:60px; border:solid thin #888; padding:0px; border-radius:4px; background-color:yellow; top:240px; left:230px">
</div>
```

Comment: While I appreciate the effort, this does not answer my question at all. I'm not asking for help to make a speech bubble (there are a million ways to do that), I'm trying to make my svg lines look cleaner (shape rendering also does not fix this).

Comment: Ah, what you want is a growing bubble but the path `stroke-width` remains the same thickness (and smooth), hence your path generation algorithm. Use `'stroke-width': '3'` in your code and you can see that it thickens at certain areas. Thinking...

Comment: Have you tried `Snap.path.toCubic(pathString)` function? Also the path generation function produces a odd twirl at the base (slow animation down to 2000ms, you'll see it).

Comment: Yeah I've noticed the odd twirl as well... Not sure how to fix it. Maybe I need to have another intermediate frame inbetween?

Answer (score 0):

I think to get nice curved corners, you will need to do two things:

1. Improve your path generation algorithm. This is because when you zoom in on your SVG, you can see that the path width gets bigger on the corners. I don't have the time or expertise to help with this one.
2. Try using different values for the [`shape-rendering` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering). They can give you significantly crisper rendering.

Comment: I wasn't specifically referring to the curved corners but rather the overall lack of solid tracing around the shape. There's way too many shades of gray within a pixel or two of the path when I would really prefer just a single strong 1px thick line throughout. I've experimented with different shape-rendering values and none of them really solve the edge strength problem.